# Codeigniter: passing whole database from model to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i am not sure why are my codes not working.

This is the Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Admin extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        if (! $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
            redirect('main/restricted');
        } else {
        $privilege = $this->session->userdata('privilege');
        if ($privilege == 'member'){
            redirect('main/restricted');
        }
        }
    }

public function index() {
        $this->load->model("model_books");
        $data2 = $this->model_books->select_book();
        $data = array(
            'title' => 'Admin Page'
        );
        $this->load->view("header", $data);
        $this->load->view("admin", $data2);
        $this->load->view("footer");
    }
```

This is the Model:

```
<?php

class Model_books extends CI_Model {
public function select_book(){
            $query = $this->db->get('books');

            if ($query){
                return $query->result();
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }

}
```

This is the View:

```
<?php
        echo $data2->content;
        ?>
```

I got around 10 books inside the database however the books in the database are not showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public function index() {
        $this->load->model("model_books");
        $data = array(
            'title' => 'Admin Page',
            'books' => $this->model_books->select_book()
        );
        $this->load->view("header", $data);
        $this->load->view("admin", $data);
        $this->load->view("footer");
    }
```

In view

```
<?php
        print_r($books);
        ?>
```

Comment: This method works, however it is only printing the last book from the book table, but i need to print the whole books table out.

Answer (score 0):

try the following in constructor function in model

$db = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);

Comment: no need for this if you are autoloading database library